# Numeric parameters for foreign keys in HQL statement

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, hql

These both work:

```
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person WHERE Company = 1",[]);
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person WHERE companyID = 1",[]);
```

"Company" is the property name, and references a "Company" entity, whilst "companyID" is the column name (a FK linked to an auto-inc PK).

However, what I'm attempting to do is more complex - it involves joins, and that requires using an alias.

So I update those two queries with an alias...

```
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person AS BaseEntity WHERE BaseEntity.Company = 1",[]);
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person AS BaseEntity WHERE BaseEntity.companyID = 1",[]);
```

The first one still works, the second throws the error:

> *Error while executing the Hibernate query.*
>
> *org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: companyID of: Person*

I have no idea why both the unaliased versions work.

Of course, if I could simply use the property name with an alias that would be fine, but when I add parameters into the mix (because a hard-coded value isn't that helpful)...

```
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person WHERE Company = ?",[1]);
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person WHERE companyID = ?",[1]);
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person AS BaseEntity WHERE BaseEntity.Company = ?",[1]);
 OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person AS BaseEntity WHERE BaseEntity.companyID = ?",[1]);
```

...all four of those fail.

The last one gives the same error as above.

The first and third both give error:

> *You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.*

I'm assuming this is because CF is trying to treat the numeric id as an entity.

The second one is CF/Hibernate being its typical unhelpful self: a *java.lang.NullPointerException* error with no details.

Is there any way to allow a numeric ID to be provided as a parameter to Hibernate?

Comment: Uh, anyone care to comment on the downvotes and the "primarily opinion-based" close vote here? :/

Comment: I was just about to say WTH. This question is *not* opinion based.

Comment: WTF? How is this 'primarily opinion based'? StackOverlords at it again?

Answer (score 2):

The solution seems to be to refer to the Company's companyID property instead of the Person's companyID column, i.e:

```
OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person AS BaseEntity WHERE BaseEntity.Company.companyID = ?",[1]);
```

The same form also works without aliases:

```
OrmExecuteQuery("FROM Person WHERE Company.companyID = ?",[1]);
```